# StatusCodeResult vs ObjectResult

Tags: asp.net-web-api, asp.net-core-webapi

Did I get it right?

I'm writing a Web API in .Net Core.

StatusCodeResult: use it, if you want just to return a status code without any content/data.

ObjectResult: if I want to return a status code and some data.

For example: a client makes a request: get person with id=1. In this case I would use OkObjectResult. If the id is not available I could return NotFoundResult (or NotFoundObjectResult if I would like to return some data like an error message).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, You are right. From the Microsoft Document:

> **StatusCodeResult:**
>
> Represents an ActionResult that when executed will produce an HTTP
> response with the given response status code.
>
> **ObjectResult:**
>
> An ActionResult that on execution will write an object to the response
> using mechanisms provided by the host.

From your example, You can just return `NotFound()`.

Let's check the constructor method of `NotFound()`:

[image]

When you don't pass any parameter, The return type is `NotFoundResult`, It will just show an empty 404 response. But when you pass a parameter into 'NotFound(xx)', The return type is  `NotFoundObjectResult`, It will show the 404 responses with the passed object.

Refer to this simple demo:

```
[HttpPost]
public IActionResult Get(int id)
{
    if (id == 3)
    {
        //only return 200 state code
        return Ok();    
    }
    else
    {
        //return 404 state code with error message.
        return NotFound("Id is not correct");
    
}
```

[image]

[image]